# dyld: Library not loaded error when running command in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-snow-leopard, dylib

When running some commands in the terminal, I get the following error message

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.62.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local//lib/libTIFF.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local//lib/libjpeg.62.dylib: can't map
    /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.62.dylib: can't map
Trace/BPT trap
```

My xcode is up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your paths begin /opt/local I assume you are using [macports](http://www.macports.org/)

If so I think you need to at least do a sudo port selfupdate as the current tiff port depends on /libjpeg.7.dylib.

Possible a complete reinstall is needed if the macports was installed under Leopard or earlier

Answer (score 3):

After you do your

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

don't forget to do a

```
sudo port upgrade outdated
```

to upgrade your existing ports. Much better than reinstalling everything :-)

Answer (score 1):

On my Leopard machine using macports, `libsdl_image` was looking for this non-installed jpeg lib. The `jpeg6b` port includes it, but at a different path (`/opt/local/lib/jpeg6b/lib/libjpeg.62.dylib`). I fixed it by doing

```
port selfupdate
port install libsdl_image
```

which upgraded libsdl_image from 1.2.8_0 to 1.2.10_2 and made the problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have never runned anything else than Snow Leopard. I have tried all kind of stuff and used about 10 hours trying to fix this problem, but with no success.

I ended up removing macports completely and installed it again.

This is what I did:

First I got a list of all my installed ports:

```
> port installed
```

Then I uninstalled everything:

```
> sudo port -f uninstall installed
```

And installed macports again: [macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php) and installed all my packages again.

It was rather tedious, but it did the trick.